# How to disable caching in Swagger UI

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger UI for documenting the APIs. I have deployed the Ui and node server( that has JSON) using docker. After deployment, when I make changes in JSON file, the same is not getting reflected in swagger-UI unless i refresh the whole page.

I tried to add `<html manifest="example.appcache">`in swagger-ui's index.html and the manifest file has the following config

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
*
```

Even after setting the manifest the JSON still gets loaded from cache. Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

There was discussions and some solutions on [Swagger repository issues](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/792) like creating a request interceptor and set the headers before the request is sent:

```
var interceptor = {
    requestInterceptor: {
        apply: function (requestObj) {

           var headers = request.Obj.headers || {};

           headers['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
           headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
           headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
           return requestObj;
       }
    }
};

// assign the request interceptor in the UI
new SwaggerClient({
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/v2/petstore.json',
  requestInterceptor: interceptor.requestInterceptor,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable caching in your browser dev tools (network tab).

[image]

Comment: It will only work when devtools is open

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 3 (Springdoc), you can simply add the following to your **application.yaml** file.

```
springdoc:
  cache:
    disabled: true
```

or related property to **application.properties** file.